# Uses of nonsmooth analysis in mathematical research

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-smooth-optimization, non-smooth-analysis

To give some context: I am aware of the uses of Convex Analysis (and its applications in Convex Optimization), I have been studying (for a while) the developments of Nonsmooth Analysis (and its applications in Nonsmooth Optimization) as traced by Frank Clarke.

While all of this work on subdifferentials and subgradients is very interesting, I am wondering about its relevance in mathematical research. I have been told some nonsmooth optimization methods have been narrowly applied in Engineering (neural nets, robotics, dynamics, ...) but I am wondering how the field connects with the rest of mathematical research.

Thank you for the insight.

Comment: See [Heinonen, Nonsmooth Calculus](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2007-44-02/S0273-0979-07-01140-8/). Connections to other areas and applications are discussed in the last section 16.

Comment: @Conifold: I believe this is unrelated to what the OP is looking for. Distributional derivatives are quite different to the generalised gradients and subgradients of Clarke's analysis.

Comment: An application area I found to be interesting was that of [total variation denoising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising#2D_signal_images), which has some properties that are preferred over L2-norm denoising but yields a convex optimization problem, which can be solved using subgradient methods.

Comment: Compressed sensing, which solves the LASSO problem, is huge!  It has revolutionized MRI.